# Creating multiple plots on the same Graph?

Tags: plot, netlogo

In my code i have a variable called hops owned by the breed ants.

```
             ants-own 
            [
                hops
                distance-gone
                distance-to-go
                target-node
                current-node
            ]
```

I want to plot the hops against the time ( ie when it takes 1st hop , it plots 1 against time n likewise) for each ant. In doing so, i should have n number of graph lines on the same plot where n is my number of ants).

i implemented it using the following code snippet, but getting only one line of graph.

```
     to do-plot

      set-current-plot "Hop Count"
      let i 0
      ask ants 
       [
         set-current-plot-pen (word who)
         set-plot-pen-color i + 15
         plot  hops 

       ]
      end
```

It would be better if different ants graph gets plotted in diffrent color.

Answer (score 3):

At setup, you need to create a plot pen for each ant using `create-temporary-plot-pen (word who)`. Are you doing this?

Also, I don't think the color line is going to turn out how you want it. In NetLogo, the main colors are 5, 15, 25, 35, and so forth. The other numbers are shades of those colors. When I'm doing something like this, I would usually do something like `10 * ( who mod 14 ) + 5`. There are 14 different colors, so `who mod 14` keeps the color number in range. You can get repeated colors this way, but it's usually not too bad.

Comment: Yes sir, We have used create-temporary-plot-pen (word who).
after doing all this we are getting a single line only with multiple colors , as against what we wanted ie a single line for all the individual ants in the graph.

Comment: Would you edit your question to include that code? Also, the ants could all be hopping the same number of times, which would put all the lines on top of each other.

Comment: It might help if you included a screen shot of the results you're getting. Sometimes actually seeing what you mean by something like “single line only with multiple colors” makes it easier to spot the problem.